# Bootstrap dropdown menu not displaying on mouseover / click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the HTML for the dropdown part:

```
<li class="dropdown">   
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="/contact-us">Contact Us <i class="fa fa-angle-down hidden-xs hidden-sm"></i></a>
    <a class="visible-xs visible-sm dropdown-menu-xs" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a> 
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/contact-us/testpage">testpage</a></li>                        
        <li><a href="/contact-us/testpage2">testpage2</a></li>                          
    </ul>
</li>
```

It just looks like this:

[image]

Nothing happens when I mouseover it, and clicking it takes me to the contact us page.

I should have all the necessary JS files:

```
<script src="/js/plugins/jquery.1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="/js/validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/sticky-tabs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/jquery.select2list.min.js"></script>
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Edit - getting this error in console:

[image]

Not sure what's causing that though, there is no HTML in there

Comment: Please check console for errors

Comment: are you loading `jquery` at the end of `body` tag or before end of `head` tag

Comment: check your visible and hidden class in html

Comment: Updated original post with error. I'm loading jquery before the end of the head tag.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766270/dropdown-menu-not-working-in-header/

Comment: Looks like your js isn't loading. What happens if you navigate to `yoursite.com/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js`?

Comment: Shouldn't be a duplicate, I am loading jquery before bootstrap,min.js. DavidG, bootstrap.min.js works fine if I navigate to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact Us <i class="fa fa-angle-down hidden-xs hidden-sm"></i></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Answer (score -1):

There were few errors in your code.

1. You are not giving id to your button.
2. Missing data-toggle="dropdown" from button
3. You are not using aria-labelledby attribute in ul.

Checkout this snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<li class="dropdown">   
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"  id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact Us <i class="fa fa-angle-down hidden-xs hidden-sm"></i></a>
    <a class="visible-xs visible-sm dropdown-menu-xs" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a> 
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a href="/contact-us/testpage">testpage</a></li>                        
        <li><a href="/contact-us/testpage2">testpage2</a></li>                          
    </ul>
</li>
```